# Converting the input form email into lowercase but last letter doesn't convert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert text input that the user types into lowercase. I have the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email").on('change keyup paste',function(){
$(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase());
 })
})
```

It doesn't transform the last letter?

Comment: Because the `keyup` *event* occurs before the value has been updated.

Comment: To add to the above, use `'input'` instead of `'change keyup paste'`

Comment: **Off Topic:** changing the value with `.val(new_value)` *while* the user is inputting means they **can't edit the value** (as the cursor will keep jumping to the end) - this is a very good way to annoy your users!

Comment: @freedomn-m maybe it's different in jquery, but it will be updated when using `addEventListener`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox unknown - but the event should still fire before as it gives you chance to *change* the value that's been input - ie what OP should be doing is changing the key value to lowercase, not the input value

Comment: Also off topic: emails are not case sensitive, I would also be offended if you converted my email to lowercase

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I changed it to input and now it doesnt add anything on input field while i typw :(

Comment: @Ica unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/sx1yz72o/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan interesting in your (deleted) fiddle is that it *doesn't* update .val() if there's no change (ie if you only enter lowercase)

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah, that's why I deleted it, as I managed to reproduce the issue you described (where entering a uppercase character in a position other than the end of the current value causes the caret to be moved). I've re-linked it in the above comment to show the OP that the main question is solved by using `input`, however.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the new code doesn't work :(  it doesnt add anything to the value field anymore

Comment: Which browser are you using? That works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, and probably more but that's all I have to hand

Comment: @Ica did you try "the new code" in the fiddle that Rory linked to?  Does it work there?

Comment: @Ica This code has no server code.  It can easily be turned into a runnable snippet and/or jsfiddle to make it easy for anyone to try and test it for you.  Can you make it runnable less than three clicks away?